# I was expect navigation drawer runed as example; however, MDNavigationDrawer perhaps executed twice

Tags: python, kivymd

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass


class HomeWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ContentNavigationDrawer(MDBoxLayout):
    pass



class main(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "APP"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.root = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
        wm = WindowManager()
        wm.add_widget(LoginWindow())
        wm.add_widget(HomeWindow())
        return wm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main().run()
```

Here is my ky file.

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    HomeWindow:

<WindowManager>:
    id:window_manager
    name:'window_manager'
<LoginWindow>:
    id:login_window
    name:'login_window'
    MDCard:
        size_hint:None,None
        size:300,500
        orientation:"vertical"
        halign:"center"
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
        padding:15
        spacing:20
        MDLabel:
            text:"Welcome!"
            halign:"center"
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id:user
            hint_text:"user"
            icon_right:"account"
            size_hint:None, None
            width:250
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
            halign:"center"
        MDTextFieldRound:
            id:password
            hint_text:"password"
            icon_right:"eye-off"
            size_hint:None, None
            width:250
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
            halign:"center"
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text:"Log in"
            size_hint:None, None
            width:150
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}
            on_press:root.manager.current="home_window"
<HomeWindow>:
    id:home_window
    name:'home_window'
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            MDScreen:
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    MDToolbar:
                        type:"top"
                        title: "Navigation Drawer"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                    Widget:
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    id:content_drawer
    orientation:"vertical"
```

I am a beginner.
When I practicing screen switch and navigation drawer, I was expected that navigation drawer would runed as an example, which is https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.0/components/navigation-drawer/index.html.
When I run the code, I was confused with a problem, which was that
`lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")` perhaps executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove one MDNavigationDrawer or you can use my code:

```
try:
    from jnius import autoclass
    python_activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
    python_activity.removeLoadingScreen()
except:
    pass


try:
    import plyer
except:
    pass
try:
    import android
except:
    pass

from time import sleep
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons

from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel 
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import TouchBehavior
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import ThreeLineAvatarListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineAvatarListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import ImageLeftWidget
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget
from kivymd.uix.list import IconRightWidget
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDListBottomSheet
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDGridBottomSheet
from kivymd.uix.filemanager import MDFileManager
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import SmartTileWithLabel
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCardSwipe

#import kivymd.uix.behaviors.MagicBehavior
from kivymd.uix.behaviors.magic_behavior import MagicBehavior
#from kivymd.uix.button import MagicButton
import sys

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import (
    NumericProperty,
    StringProperty,
    BooleanProperty,
    OptionProperty,
    ListProperty,
    ObjectProperty,
)
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.metrics import sp

from kivymd.font_definitions import theme_font_styles
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.label import MDIcon

from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.scatterlayout import ScatterLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen,WipeTransition,FadeTransition,FallOutTransition,RiseInTransition,CardTransition        

from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.setupconfig import USE_SDL2
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty

import requests
import time
import shutil
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
import os
worm = os.getcwd()+"/"
Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"

def android_dir(a):
    try:
        from android.storage import app_storage_path
        from android.storage import primary_external_storage_path
        from android.storage import secondary_external_storage_path
        pt1=app_storage_path()+"/"
        if a==1:
            pt2=primary_external_storage_path()+"/"
            return pt2
        if a==2:
            pt3=secondary_external_storage_path()+"/"
            return pt3
        return pt2
    except:
        return worm

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
    pass



class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    def set_color_item(self, instance_item):
        '''Called when tap on a menu item.'''

        # Set the color of the icon and text for the menu item.
        for item in self.children:
            if item.text_color == self.theme_cls.primary_color:
                item.text_color = self.theme_cls.text_color
                #self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
                break
        instance_item.text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color


Window.softinput_mode = "below_target"

#Window.size=(350,600)

KV = '''
#:import toast kivymd.toast.toast
#:import Snackbar kivymd.uix.snackbar.Snackbar
#:import Clipboard kivy.core.clipboard.Clipboard
#:import MDLabel kivymd.uix.label.MDLabel
#:import MDCard kivymd.uix.card.MDCard
#:import MDTextFieldRound kivymd.uix.textfield.MDTextFieldRound
#:import MDTextButton kivymd.uix.button.MDTextButton
#:import MDIconButton kivymd.uix.button.MDIconButton
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button.MDRaisedButton
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
#:import runTouchApp kivy.app.runTouchApp
#:import MDFileManager kivymd.uix.filemanager
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button
#:import Bubble kivy.uix.bubble.Bubble
#:import * kivy.graphics
#:import ProgressBar kivy.uix.progressbar
#:import OneLineListItem kivymd.uix.list.OneLineListItem
#:import ThreeLineAvatarListItem kivymd.uix.list.ThreeLineAvatarListItem
#:import MagicBehavior kivymd.uix.behaviors.MagicBehavior
####################################################

<On1>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    border_radius: "-3dp"
    ripple_behavior: True
    elevation: 20
    size: "320dp", "100dp"
    size_hint: None, None
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    #background: app.w+"toolbar.png"
        
    AnchorLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        blanks1:
        FitImage:
            source: app.w + "bbay.png"
            size_hint: .5, None
            height: text_box.height+100
            MDBoxLayout:
                id: text_box
                orientation: "vertical"
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: "40dp"
                padding: 0, "90dp", "90dp", "90dp"
                #pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}

    MDLabel:
        id: user20
        markup: True
        text: "\\n\\n[b][color=ffffff]   Tarkhan Simarik\\n[/b]   [color=ffffff]Cód. de Vendedor: 5555\\n[color=ffffff]   Idioma: \\n"
        #font_style: "H5"
        #halign: "center"
        size_hint_y: 20
        height: self.texture_size[1]




# Menu item in the DrawerList list.
<ItemDrawer>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,1,1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            ##source: app.w+"toolbar.png"
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    #theme_text_color: "Custom"
    
    on_release: app.action(str(root.icon)) #toast(str(root.icon)) #self.parent.set_color_item(self)

    IconLeftWidget:
        id: icon
        icon: root.icon
        #theme_text_color: "Custom"
        #text_color: root.text_color


<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,0,0, 0)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"
    
    ScrollView:
        padding: dp(10)
        default_size_hint: None, None

        DrawerList:
            id: md_list
            size_hint_y: None
            MDCard:
                orientation: "vertical"
                border_radius: "-3dp"
                ripple_behavior: True
                elevation: 20
                size: "320dp", "100dp"
                size_hint: None, None
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                #background: "Photos/pro.jpg"
                    
                AnchorLayout:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": -.1, "center_y": .5}
                    FitImage:
                        source: "Photos/pro.jpg"
                        size_hint: 1, None
                        height: text_box.height #+100
                        MDBoxLayout:
                            id: text_box
                            orientation: "vertical"
                            adaptive_height: True
                            spacing: "40dp"
                            padding: 0, "90dp", "90dp", "90dp"
                            #pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}

                MDLabel:
                    id: user20
                    markup: True
                    text: "\\n\\n[b][color=ffffff]   JBSIDIS\\n[/b]   [color=ffffff]------\\n[color=ffffff]   : \\n"
                    #font_style: "H5"
                    #halign: "center"
                    size_hint_y: 20
                    height: self.texture_size[1]


Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        id: mt
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        title: app.t
        elevation: 10
        #md_bg_color: (.1,.80,.5,.3)
        font_stye: "H5"
        #source: app.w+"toolbar.png"
        hint_animation: True
        
        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]


    NavigationLayout: #kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <MDNavigationLayout>

        ScreenManager:
            id: MainActivity

            Screen:
                id: SecondActivity
                name: "main"
        
                BoxLayout:
                    id: superbody_jbsidis
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    spacing: dp(20)

                    MDCard:
                        id: jbsidis_will_be_card
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        border_radius: "-3dp"
                        ripple_behavior: True
                        padding: dp(10)
                        size: "320dp", "250dp"
                        size_hint: .5, None
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        background: "Photos/pro.jpg"
                        TextInput:
                            markup: True
                            font_size: dp(40)
                            size_hint: 1.1,1.1
                            #font_color: (0,0,0,1)
                            text: "Created by jbsidis " #open("file.txt").read()
                            id: bx1
                            background_color: [0,0,0,0]
                            foreground_color: [1,1,1,1]
                            halign: "left"
                            #multiline: True
                            hint_text: 'Insert Text'
                        FloatLayout:
                            BoxLayout:
                                pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.2, "center_y": .5}
                                MDIconButton:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgba: (1,1,1,.5)
                                        Rectangle:
                                            pos: self.pos
                                            size: self.size
                                    icon: "pencil"
                                    on_release: app.root.ids.bx1.focus=True
                                MDIconButton:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgba: (1,1,1,.5)
                                        Rectangle:
                                            pos: self.pos
                                            size: self.size
                                    icon: "delete"
                                    on_release:
                                        app.root.ids.superbody_jbsidis.remove_widget(app.root.ids.jbsidis_will_be_card)
                        

                    MDCard:
                        id: jbsidis_will_be_card2
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        border_radius: "-3dp"
                        ripple_behavior: True
                        padding: dp(10)
                        size: "320dp", "250dp"
                        size_hint: .5, None
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        background: "Photos/pro.jpg"
                        TextInput:
                            markup: True
                            font_size: dp(40)
                            size_hint: 1.1,1.1
                            #font_color: (0,0,0,1)
                            text: "Created by jbsidis " #open("file.txt").read()
                            id: bx2
                            background_color: [0,0,0,0]
                            foreground_color: [1,1,1,1]
                            halign: "left"
                            #multiline: True
                            hint_text: 'Insert Text'
                        FloatLayout:
                            BoxLayout:
                                pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.2, "center_y": .5}
                                MDIconButton:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgba: (1,1,1,.5)
                                        Rectangle:
                                            pos: self.pos
                                            size: self.size
                                    icon: "pencil"
                                    on_release: app.root.ids.bx2.focus=True
                                MDIconButton:
                                    canvas.before:
                                        Color:
                                            rgba: (1,1,1,.5)
                                        Rectangle:
                                            pos: self.pos
                                            size: self.size
                                    icon: "delete"
                                    on_release:
                                        app.root.ids.superbody_jbsidis.remove_widget(app.root.ids.jbsidis_will_be_card2)
                        
                
                Widget:
        

##                BoxLayout:
##                    id: m5
##                    spacing: dp(10)
##                    #padding: dp(20)
##                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .43}
##                    orientation: "vertical"
##                    BoxLayout:
##                        id: s_res9
##                        size_hint_y: None #None
##                        height: self.minimum_height
##                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
##                        orientation: "vertical"
##                    RecycleView:
##                        id: rvvv9
##                        key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
##                        key_size: 'height'
##
##                        RecycleBoxLayout:
##                            id: jbsidis
##                            padding: dp(10)
##                            spacing: dp(1)
##                            #default_size: None, dp(75)
##                            default_size_hint: 1, None
##                            size_hint_y: None
##                            height: self.minimum_height
##                            orientation: 'vertical'

                    Widget:


        MDNavigationDrawer:
            opening_time: 0.1
            swipe_distance: 2
            swipe_edge_width: 40
            #scrim_color: [.1,.2,.4,1]
            #spacing: dp(5)
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                id: content_drawer

<Menu1>:
    name: "menu1"
##    canvas.before:
##        Color:
##            rgba: (1,1,1, 1)
##        Rectangle:
##            source: app.w+"bgx.png"
##            pos: self.pos
##            size: self.size
    

##    MDToolbar:
##        canvas.before:
##            Color:
##                rgba: (1,1,1, .8)
##            Rectangle:
##                source: app.w+"toolbar.png"
##                pos: self.pos
##                size: self.size
##        id: mt
##        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
##        title: app.t
##        elevation: 10
##        md_bg_color: (.1,.80,.5,.3)
##        font_stye: "H5"
##        #source: app.w+"toolbar.png"
##        hint_animation: True
##        MDIconButton:
##            icon: "menu"
        
        #left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: print("")]]
        
    BoxLayout:
        id: m51
        spacing: dp(10)
        #padding: dp(20)
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .43}
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            id: s_res91
            size_hint_y: None #None
            height: self.minimum_height
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}
            orientation: "vertical"
        RecycleView:
            id: rvvv91
            key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
            key_size: 'height'

            RecycleBoxLayout:
                id: jbsidis1
                padding: dp(10)
                spacing: dp(1)
                #default_size: None, dp(75)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
#######Class Audio List########            
<ItemConfirm0>:
    source: app.w+"bbay.png"
<ItemConfirm>:
    markup: True
    ItemConfirm0:

'''


from kivymd.uix.list import ImageLeftWidget

class ItemConfirm0(ImageLeftWidget):
    pass
class ItemConfirm(OneLineIconListItem):
    divider = None
    source = StringProperty()
    text= StringProperty()
    us=None
##    def on_release(self):
##        b=str(self.text)
##        us=self.ids['cy_']
##        us.text=b
##        us.md_bg_color= [.1,.8,1,.9]
##        return 0
    def set_icon(self, instance_check):
        instance_check.active = True
        check_list = instance_check.get_widgets(instance_check.group)
        for check in check_list:
            if check != instance_check:
                check.active = False
    pass
##################################

#MenuNaibDrawerChooser
class blanks1(BoxLayout):
    pass
class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass
class On1(MDCard):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def vn1(self):
        user20=self.ids['user20']
        print(user20.text)
        try:
            xx=open(app.w+"cookie.dic").read()
            f=str(xx).split("]")
            z="\n\n[b][color=ffffff]   "+str(f[1])+"\n[/b]   [color=ffffff]Cód. de Vendedor: "+str(f[2])+"\n[color=ffffff]   Idioma: \n"
            self.ids.user20.text=z
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
    def vn(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda x:self.vn1(),5)
    pass
class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    divider=None
    icon = StringProperty()
    text_color = ListProperty((0, 0, 0, 1))



class ExpressBay(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.snackbar = None
        self.w = worm
        self.rr = 10
        self.t="jbsidis"
        self.sb="15sp" #"15sp"
        self.mdc=[0,0,0, .1]
        self.tos="hello"
        
        

    def build(self):
        #self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        global app
        app=MDApp.get_running_app()
        #Clock.schedule_once(lambda x:app.io1(),10)
        #Clock.schedule_once(lambda x:app.io2(),10)
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    
    def n1(self,t,m):
        try:
            plyer.notification.notify(title=t, message=m, app_icon=app.w+"xbay.png")
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            
    def n(self, title='', message='', app_name='', app_icon='',timeout=10, ticker='', toast=False):
        plyer.notification.notify(title=title, message=message, app_name=app_name, app_icon=app_icon,timeout=timeout, ticker=ticker, toast=toast)
        app.v(0.2)
           
    def hilo(self,fx):
        import threading
        #thread = threading.Thread(target = app.sound_list, args=(types,))
        thread = threading.Thread(target = fx)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        #app.hilo(app.camx())
        
    def se(self,a):
        if os.path.isfile(app.w+"set.dic")==True and a==0:
            h=open(app.w+"set.dic").read().split("]")[0]
            return str(h)
        if os.path.isfile(app.w+"set.dic")==True and a==1:
            h=open(app.w+"set.dic").read().split("]")[1]
            return str(h)
        return ""

    def check(self, obj):
        
        rs = "s"
        try:
            rs = getinfo(obj)
        except:
            pass
        if rs == "Unknown Error":
            toast('Unknown Error')
        else:
            try:
                    r = json.loads(rs)
                    version = str(r['version'])
                    country = str(r['city']) + " " + str(r['region']) + " "+ str(r['country_name'])
                    lit = str(r['latitude'])
                    long = str(r['longitude'])
                    self.root.ids.result.text = "\n" + self.root.ids.target_ip.text + "\n\n" + version + "\n\n" + country + "\n\n" + lit + "\n\n" + long
            except Exception as e:
                    version = str("New version")
                    country = str("New Country") + " " + str("New City") + " "+ str("New Name")
                    lit = str("1.232323")
                    long = str("3437434")
                    self.root.ids.result.text = "\n" + self.root.ids.target_ip.text + "\n\n" + version + "\n\n" + country + "\n\n" + lit + "\n\n" + long

      
    def tagm(self):
        #On1().vn()
        try:
            xx=open(app.w+"cookie.dic").read()
            f=str(xx).split("]")
            z="\n\n[b][color=ffffff]   "+str(f[1])+"\n[/b]   [color=ffffff]Cód. de Vendedor: "+str(f[2])+"\n[color=ffffff]   Idioma: \n"
            #self.ids.user20.text=z
            self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.user20.text=z
            app.root.ids.rvvv9.data=[]
            #fffapp.root.ids.rvvv9.data.append({"viewclass": "Operas","markup": True}) #.data.append({"viewclass": "VenderRecargas","markup": True})
##            self.root.ids.rvvv9.data.append({"viewclass": "pp1","markup": True})
##            self.root.ids.rvvv9.data.append({"viewclass": "Operas","markup": True})
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

    def v(self,s):
        try:
            plyer.vibrator.vibrate(s)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
    def action(self,a):
        man=['chat-processing', 'shield-airplane-outline', 'history', 'bitcoin', 'bell-ring-outline', 'face-profile', 'credit-card-plus-outline', 'account-circle-outline', 'pencil', 'logout']
        if a==man[-1]:
            app.root.ids.nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()
            app.notti(title="",text="Sesión finalizada")
            #app.root.ids.MainActivity.current = "loginpage"

    def on_start(self):
        #self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        icons_item = {
            "chat-processing": "[color=999999]jbsidis1",
            "shield-airplane-outline": "[color=999999]jbsidis2",
            "history": "[color=999999]jbsidis3",
            "bitcoin": "[color=999999]jbsidis4",
            "bell-ring-outline": "[color=999999]jbsidis5",
            "face-profile": "[color=999999]jbsidis6",
            "credit-card-plus-outline": "[color=999999]jbsidis7",
            "account-circle-outline": "[color=999999]jbsidis8",
            "pencil": "[color=999999]jbsidis9",
            "logout": "[color=999999]jbsidis10"
        }
        
        #app.root.ids.MainActivity.add_widget(Login())
        #app.root.ids.MainActivity.current = "login"
        #app.root.ids.MainActivity.add_widget(LoginPage())
        #app.root.ids.MainActivity.add_widget(Menu1())
        #app.root.ids.MainActivity.add_widget(RegisterPage())
        #app.root.ids.MainActivity.add_widget(Camera1())
        #app.root.ids.MainActivity.current = "login"
        
        for icon_name in icons_item.keys():
            self.root.ids.content_drawer.ids.md_list.add_widget(
                ItemDrawer(icon=icon_name, text=icons_item[icon_name])
            )

      
    def notti(self,title="",text=""):
        self.dialog=MDDialog(
            title=title,
            text="[color=000000]"+text,
            radius=[self.rr,self.rr,self.rr,self.rr],
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="ACEPTAR",
                    text_color=[0,1,0,1],
                    on_release=lambda x:(self.dialog.dismiss(force=True))),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()
      
   


ExpressBay().run()
```

Here is the image:
[image]